# Javascript reg ex for quiz

Tags: javascript

hello I am developing a basic javascript quiz.quiz contains a questions called study of animals is called? the answer zoology should be typed in a text field......basically when user enters the answer zoology in the text field..the quiz must accept uppercase,lowercase and mixed letters as answer..for example: ZooLOGy or ZOOLOGY. Please tell me how can I do that??

This is the javascript code i developed

```
if (Q1[0].value == "zoology") {
  quest4 = 1;
}theGrade = (quest1 + quest2 + quest3 + quest4).toString();
alert("your score is " + thisGrade);
```

I know I have to use reg ex [a-z] [A-Z]..can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use RegEx, simply convert the actual value you want to check to [`lowercase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)/[`uppercase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) and have the expected value in the same case, like this

```
if (Q1[0].value.toLowerCase() === "zoology")
```

or

```
if (Q1[0].value.toUpperCase() === "ZOOLOGY")
```

Comment: user enters the answer "zoology" into the textfield in the quiz. if the user types the word "zoology" in uppercase or lowercase or mixed case letters the quiz must accept that as the right answer and give a score...any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is interested in how to solve this with a regex (although it's admittedly overkill for just case insensitivity), here's what that would look like:

```
if(/^zoology$/i.test(Q1[0])) // do stuff
```

The `^` tells the regex to make sure that this is at the beginning of the string, and the `$` tells it to make sure it's at the end. The `i` flag turns off case sensitivity. In combination, this checks to make sure that the only characters are the word "zoology", regardless of case.